# How to handle unsuccessful requests in service layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture

Let's say I have the following rest api endpoint which uses service layer:

```
[HttpGet("id")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
    var entity = _someService.GetById(id);
    
    return Ok(entity);
}
```

And in service method it turns out that user has no privileges to access that entity:

```
public Entity GetById(int id)
{
    var entity = _repository.Get(id)
    
    if(entity.OwnerId != CurrentUserId) // true
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or it simply doesn't exist:

```
public Entity GetById(int id)
{
    var entity = _repository.Get(id)
    
    if(entity is null) // true
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What's the best way to handle such scenarios and let a user know that something went wrong by setting a suitable status code on the response?

What I can think of is define result class which contains also request result like:

```
public class RequestResult<T>
{
    public T Result {get; set;}
    public int StatusCode {get; set;} // 200, 404, 403 ...
}
```

or (which I personally like more) define and throw ForbiddenException or NotFoundException and handle these in ExceptionHandlingMiddleware by setting suitable response status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service layer isn't the correct place to define HTTP responses; this is the responsibility of your controller.

[`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-3.1) defines a number of methods to generate various HTTP responses, including `Ok` in your example, which returns a 200.

There is also `Forbid` and `NotFound`, which should satisfy your requirements.

For example, if the entity is not found, have your service return null:

```
[HttpGet("id")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
    var entity = _someService.GetById(id);

    if (entity == null) return NotFound();
    
    return Ok(entity);
}
```

If the service determines that the user does not have access, then an exception would probably be appropriate:

```
public Entity GetById(int id)
{
    var entity = _repository.Get(id)
    
    if (entity.OwnerId != CurrentUserId) // true
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpGet("id")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
    Entity entity;
    try
    {
        entity = _someService.GetById(id);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return Forbid();
    }

    if (entity == null) return NotFound();
    
    return Ok(entity);
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's better than using middleware to handle exceptions? After all, we could have other exception types to handle and this solution broadens our controllers' code.

Comment: @del There isn't anything to be achieved by reducing the number of lines in your controller code. Everything in `GetById` above is related to the processing of a HTTP request, which is the purpose of a controller method. Of course, if the exception handling logic needs to be re-usable then middleware is one way to achieve that. The key message is that your service layer should not concern itself with UI-specific concepts such as a HTTP response, just as your controller shouldn't contain business logic.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to handle such scenarios and return either 403 or 404?

Per hTTO definition 404 - not found.

403 is forbidden - which makes no sense in terms of general security and READ operations. Basically: if you are not alloowerd to read it, you are also generally not allowed to know it exists or not. This is standard these days - I do not tell you taht your password is wrong, I tell you username OR password wrong. I never provide security relevant information.

So, 403 is then isolated to update operations whree you are allowed to read, but forbidden to update (or delete). Not allowed to read is turned into a 404 (not found) for security issues.

Comment: I know in that case 403 should be returned, but that was just quick example. What I'm asking about is how can I set proper status code on the response, not what the status code should be.

Comment: That is not what you ask at all. Generally throw an exception that sets the status code.. Possibly wrap that in a handler into aJson Error object.

Comment: Of course, it is what I was asking about :)) Thanks for your answer, I will probably use handler.